# How to customize UI of a dialog returned from GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog?

Tags: android

I have an android app where I have customized the activity layouts with my required themes/colors/title bars/etc.
I need to depend on Google Play services. So, I do the following:

```
int resultCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
...
Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                resultCode,
                this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
```

The problem is, the dialog appears as a blank one, meaning all white. I want to customize this dialog to look like the rest of my UI - blue colored header, grey background, etc.

I am unable to find a way to do the above. Could you please provide any input ?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I missed to say that my app needs to run on devices with API version 8 and higher.